# rewrites and custom links in page need help with add_rewrite_rule

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, forms, rewrite-rules

I have one page with edited permalink, like, `address.com/detail/`
I need to send there some values by GET request, so i would like the link looks like `/detail/value1/value2/`

i added this code in

```
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rules');  
function rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_tag('%value1%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_tag('%value2%', '([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('detail/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$','detail/?value1=$matches[1]&value2=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
```

but it doesn't work actually, and i can't get which rewrite rule structure i should use to make it works. value1 and value2 was added to wp_query array. may anyone help?

```
flush_rewrite_rules
```

didn't help, also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal rewrite rules should all point to `index.php`. You also need to set the proper query vars so that the main query can successfully run, in this case, to query for your `detail` page.

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    'detail/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$',
    'index.php?pagename=detail&value1=$matches[1]&value2=$matches[2]',
    'top'
);
```